# Django forgets .using database on resolving foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a model for my legacy database created by manage.py inspectdb, which accesses the database named 'edlserver' in settings, one of many databases used for the project. I cannot change the database layout.

It has the following classes (among other irrelevant ones):

One for Logging entries.

```
class Logs(models.Model):
  time = models.DateTimeField()
  job = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_job')
  msg = models.TextField()

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'logs'
```

Another one for Jobs (that the job field references)

```
class Jobs(models.Model):
  job_type = models.ForeignKey(JobTypes, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_job_type')
  time_start = models.DateTimeField()
  time_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  pid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'jobs'
```

And another one for JobTypes.

```
class JobTypes(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  max_processes = models.IntegerField()

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'job_types'
```

The view for django-rest-framework looks like this

```
class EDLLogList(generics.ListAPIView):
  serializer_class = EDLLogsSerializer
  filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
  filter_class = EDLLogsFilter    

  def get_queryset(self):
    if not 'job_name' in self.request.GET:
      raise ParameterRequired('job_name')
    else:
      return Logs.objects.all().using('edlserver')
```

It uses the Filter:

```
class EDLLogsFilter(filters.FilterSet):
  time_start = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="time", lookup_type='gte')
  time_end   = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="time", lookup_type='lte')
  job_name   = django_filters.MethodFilter()      

  class Meta:
    model = Logs
    fields = ()

  def filter_job_name(self, queryset, job_name):
    try:
      q = queryset.filter(job__job_type__name=job_name)[:10000]
    except:
      raise InternalError()

    if len(q) < 1 and 
       len(JobTypes.objects.all().using('edlserver').filter(name=job_name)) < 1:
         raise InvalidParameter(job_name, 'job_name')
    else:
        return q
```

and the Serializer:

```
class EDLLogsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  time = serializers.DateTimeField()
  job_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  message = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  class Meta:
    model = Logs
    fields = ('job_name','time', 'message')

  def get_job_name(self, obj):
    return obj['id_job__id_job_type__name']

  def get_message(self, obj):
    return obj.msg
```

Problem is I get a `TypeError: 'Logs' object is not subscriptable` in `get_job_name()` in the Serializer, coming from the psycopg2 module - the database is a MySQL database, however. The fact that the first query has a queryset with len > 0 during debugging shows that the model is okay, and django uses the MySQL backend for getting the data. On resolving the foreign key something goes wrong and the (i think) default database gets used, which is PostGreSQL.

Is this a bug?

If not, what can I do? I was thinking about a router, which would resolve a Meta field. That would mean a lot of change to other models so I'd like to not do this. Any ideas?

EDIT: settings for databases

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'pic',
    'USER' : 'pic-5437',
    'PASSWORD' : '',    
    'HOST' : 'host1.url.com',
    'PORT' : '5432'    
},
'...' : {
    ...
},
'edlserver': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': 'host2.url.com',
    'NAME': 'edl',
    'USER': 'edl_ro',
    'PASSWORD': '',
}
```

Comment: please update your question with the databases section of your settings.py and please leave out the unnecessary models

Comment: The models are all needed as they show the foreign key relationships. I' edited in the databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign keys add an attribute to the model that is itself a model instance. To follow the complete relation from `Logs` to `JobType`, simply use attribute lookups:

```
def get_job_name(self, obj):
    return obj.job.job_type.name
```

This would be the normal use-case. If multiple databases are used and django uses the wrong database while resolving the foreign key, it can be done manually:

```
 return JobTypes.objects.all().using('edlserver').filter(id=
   Jobs.objects.all().using('edlserver').filter(id=
   obj.job_id)[0].job_type_id)[0].name
```

Another option would be to introduce a Meta field in the model, like this:

```
import django.db.models.options as options
options.DEFAULT_NAMES = options.DEFAULT_NAMES + ('in_db',)

class MyModel(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    in_db = 'edlserver'
```

Then a database router is needed:

```
class DatabaseMetaRouter(object):
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Route to the given in_db database in Meta
    """
    if hasattr(model._meta, 'in_db'):
        return model._meta.in_db
    else:
        return 'default'

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Route to the given in_db database in Meta
    """
    if hasattr(model._meta, 'in_db'):
        return model._meta.in_db
    else:
        return 'default'

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Always allow
    """
    return True

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Always allow
    """
    return True
```

Comment: Okay. That still produces the exact same error: `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "jobs" does not exist
LINE 1: ...bs"."time_end", "jobs"."pid", "jobs"."title" FROM "jobs" WHE...`. However if i follow the relation manually with `.using('edlserver')` I get the right value. So i conclude it's really django not knowing what database to use. Is there a difference speed-wise if I do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that obj here is an instance of `Logs`

```
def get_job_name(self, obj):
   return obj['id_job__id_job_type__name']
```

Django models look like dictionaries, smell like dictionaries but they are not dictionaries. The correct usage is:

```
  return obj.job.job_type.name
```

I recommend that you open up a django shell, load a single instead of Logs and use the help() command and experiment with the paths.

As for the second issue, the wrong database been used for the queries, you will either need to define a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) or add [using()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#using) in your queries.

Comment: I've just tried it. `AttributeError: 'Logs' object has no attribute 'id_job__id_job_type__name'` ist the result. I've also tried `return obj.job.job_type.name`, resulting in a `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "jobs" does not exist
LINE 1: ...bs"."time_end", "jobs"."pid", "jobs"."title" FROM "jobs" WHE...` . I have the dotted notation on another place in the project where it works for the auth model (which is in the default database).

Comment: I voted +1. But I'm getting down voted too. Sorry. I'm really glad you're trying to help.

Comment: @e4c5 Don't assume. I downvoted because your answer is wrong and puts the OP on the wrong track. Following relations on model instances uses simple attribute access, only query lookups use the double underscore syntax.

Comment: @knbk good point, I had mixed up the query and the instance here, however at the time you had voted, I had merely copy pasted the OP's code and the original answer solved the original question asked.

Comment: "The correct usage is: `return obj.id_job__id_job_type__name`" is part of your original answer and is the reason I downvoted.

Comment: as I said, I mixed up between queryset and instances and changed to code to resolve the incorrect dictionary type access the OP was making

Comment: anyway @knbk fair call on your part too, no hard feeling +1 for your answer from me (withdrawing my down vote hehe)

Comment: using() has precedence